# How to update specific columns of access database using datagridview column name in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that it's columnNames are equal to my columns in `access database`

Now I want this:
whene user click on `savebtn` all of `datagridview` columns values automatically updated to my database,
I've tried this code but it get me `syntax error` :

> {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@1Where FeedID=@feedID'."}

where is the problem?

```
public void UpdatetFeeds(DataGridView dgv)
{
    string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    int FeedID = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

    using (OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon))
    {
        Connection.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            Cmd.Connection = Connection;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
            {
                string columnName = dgv.Columns[column.Index].Name;
                object columnValue = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[column.Index].Value;

                Cmd.CommandText = @"Update tFeeds Set " + columnName + " =@"
                    + columnValue + "Where FeedID=@feedID";

                Cmd.Parameters.Add("@feedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = FeedID;


                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems at least you lost space

```
" Where FeedID=@feedID";
```

Also, what kind of data you have here: `" =@" + columnValue + "`. Seems you need braskets here: `" =@'" + columnValue + "'`

Comment: yes I lost that space and after that code executed, But instead of updating cell bu column value, cell updated with FeedID parameters value

Comment: data type are string, int and double,
it's okay that I use a object? or not?

Comment: But you have only one parameter @feedId. If columnValue is string - you need bradkets. So brtter add one more parameter to avoid problems with data types. And use `columnName = @feedValue`. New param: `Cmd.Parameters.Add("@feedValue", ...`